# When to use a container and when to pass props?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux and I've being doing a lot of reading.

I don't fully understand the difference between using a container and not using a container. If I have an Attribute component that holds a DataSelect component I can:

1. Define methods/data in the Attribute container and pass them as props to the DataSelect component.
2. Use a container to wrap the DataSelect and populate what it needs from the Store.

Without container for DataSelect:

```
  // import ...
  import DataSelect from './components/DataSelect';

  // render ...
  <DataSelect dataset={ this.props.dataset } />
```

With container for DataSelect:

```
  // import ...
  import DataSelect from './containers/DataSelect';

  // render ...
  <DataSelect />
```

What's confusing for me is that the second approach means component hierarchy does not mean much and all the contained components deal directly with the store. Could anyone help me understand the difference?

**UPDATE:**

Performance-wise, if this diagram I've prepared is correct*, it seems that using containers can reduce DOM comparisons, is it right? On the left side, a state change in Datasets will trigger a check to see whether the entire Attribute component (+subchilds) should render. On the right side a change in Datasets would only check whether the DataSelect component should render. Is it right? If so, is there a significant performance benefit for using containers?

*Diagram:
[image: redux diagram]

Comment: This is not exactly related but read my answer to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38776430/2611927

Comment: Component hierarchy means what you make it mean: there's nothing that says a container can't hold other containers. "Contained components" would still deal directly with the store, the difference in your example is at what "level" those containers live.

Comment: After playing around with Relay for a bit, I've started using Redux similarly, i.e. fetch data the component needs directly inside the component. Most likely it slightly degrades the performance (just an assumption, not tested), but it's much easier to get the complete picture about the component with looking at just one file.

Comment: t seems to me that the more containers I use and if I only pass the exact state which is needed to the inner-components and nothing else the less DOM comparisons will happen when the states changes. Is it correct? I've added a Diagram to the questions to illustrate this thought.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak yes, I guess you're referring to data fetched from remote. But how do you pass around data you already have in the store?

Comment: @Guy, no I was referring to where you'd put `connect` and `mapStateToProps` functions. I put them directly to the component that needs the props, because passing the props down the component tree can get tedious in large projects. I am not saying it's the right thing to do, just what I prefer for better productivity.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I see how it can make things simpler but doesn't it mean you couple the data and the component? if you'd want to use the component in another place with other data you'd need to start separating it...

Comment: @Guy depends on component, I don't do it for all of them, e.g. won't do that for a custom styled button, but most of them. And I don't do the distinction between components and containers, because that only increases the complexity and time spent searching. The `mapStateToProps` receives `ownProps` attribute, which can be used to pull different data from state, depending on component's context, e.g. user id, to display different user profile. If the component is used to display very different data, you'll probably want to create a new component sooner or later.